# with .htaccess how do I remove slashes from some point?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to make a user system, where the URL is like:

> test/user/[name]

It all works, but if you try:

> test/user/name/something

It doesn't work. Is there any way to remove the slashes from that certain point, so that:

> test/user/name/something

will go to:

> test/user/name

How do I edit this, so it works as mentioned above:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} user/(.*)
RewriteRule user/(.*) something/test/user.php?user=$1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place this rule as your first rule in your root `/test/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /test/

RewriteRule ^(user/\w+)/.+$ /$1 [L,NC,R]

RewriteRule ^user/(.+)$ user.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} user/(.*)
RewriteRule user/(.*) http://localhost/test/user.php?user=$1 This is what I had, can you update it so it matches?

Comment: Can you edit and your question and provide your complete existing .htaccess?

Comment: I does work, to some extend. When the url: test/user/name/ is typed, it loads the page, without css... Help

Comment: For css/js problem, use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.